# Trying to add default text to show before called header text

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Trying to add default text (LEARN MORE:) in same h5 heading just before the called get_the_title hook.

what shows now example:

> MLS# T3110937 9313 MANDRAKE CT, TAMPA, FL 33647

Example of adding LEARN MORE: always being added before the called title hook:

> LEARN MORE: MLS# T3110937 9313 MANDRAKE CT, TAMPA, FL 33647

Here is the code I am working with:

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><?php echo balanceTags($title);?></h1>

    <li>
      <div class="pull-left"><?php echo balanceTags($title);?> </div>
        <h5>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
              <?php echo get_the_title();?> 
          </div>
        </h5>
    </li>             
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is a little wrong: you didn't add an `ul` `ol` before `li` element and you put a `div` inside an `h5` that doesn't take sense...

Comment: Sorry DaFois, My skills mediocre at best with code. It is showing on site though. If you would, could you add corrections and show me how to add the LEARN MORE: (default text before the called header text)?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <?php echo 'Learn More: ' . get_the_title();?> 
</div>
```

To concatenate in php, add a `.` between two or more output variables.

You can also put the text on the outside of the PHP tag.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    Learn More: <?php echo get_the_title();?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Daniel that was it. Worked perfectly! Thank You So Much! As to DaFois comments should I worry about the ul ol before li

Comment: @Joe You can also put the text on the outside of the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you also need the permalink on that text.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><?php echo balanceTags($title);?></h1>
    <div class="pull-left"><?php echo balanceTags($title);?></div>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">

              <?php the_title(); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Learn More</a>

    </h5>            
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also give a bounce to this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/

Comment: Hi DaFois, Both of your answers worked. Also, I just deleted the li's